# Unable to keep content in the left sidebar data in django page

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am building a website based on django.Below find my models:

I am facing a problem to keep the static data in the left sidebar. Whenever I click category list in the left sidebar it goes to detail of the corresponding category page.In the meantime, I am not able to see the category list data in the left sidebar.I understand that problem are located **block text1** in base.html and index.html.Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue is that base.html cannot access the block named text1 when you call detail.html.

What you want to do is define text1 in base.html so both templates can access it.

EDIT: that means too you'll need to provide categories in the detail view, too

```
def detail(request,projectname_id):
   jobs=Projectname.objects.get(pk=projectname_id)
   project_name=Projectname.objects.order_by('-name')[:5]
   context = {'jobs': jobs, 'categories':project_name}
   return render(request,'buildstatus/detail.html', context)
```

Comment: Still not able to see data in the left sidebar when I click the value in left content.It is showing only one either index or detail but not both.Do I need to edit the detail.html?

Comment: After editing details it's working now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure thing. One more thing, if 'categories' never changes you can add it to request.session instead of context in views.index and only have to call it once:             request.session.categories=Projectname.objects.order_by('-name')[:5], then access it like {{ request.session.categories }} in your templates.